# C# search checklistbox on textbox but don't remember checked or copy record twice to checklistbox C#

Tags: c#, search, textbox, arguments, checklistbox

i have problems with searching checklistbox in textbox. When I have 1 parameter

```
ladujZBazy(string mustContains)
```

When I checked items on list in checkedListBox1 and search some items using textBox1 my previous check is gone.

I add 2nd parameter to your function(bool type)

```
void ladujZBazy(string mustContains, bool dropIndexes)
```

which will by default be false

```
private void dbopakowania_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ladujZBazy(null, false); 
    }
```

and And then call textbox's TextChanged event as false.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ladujZBazy(textBox1.Text, false); //false
    }
```

This time checked is not gone but copy record twice to checklistbox.. When value boolean is true I checked items on list in checkedListBox1 and search some items using textBox1 my previous check is gone. I want when i checked and search some items using textBox1 my previous checked is not gone and don't copy record twice to checklistbox.
Full Code:

```
    namespace Email_Sender
       {
 public partial class dbopakowania : Form
      {
     EmailSender emailsender;
    public List<List<string>> listOpakowaniaTabela = new List<List<string>>();
    public string doZamowienia = "";
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    string typZgloszenia;

    public dbopakowania(EmailSender _emailsender, string _typZgloszenia)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.emailsender = _emailsender;                        //przechwycenie obiektu EmailSender do lokalnego obiektu tego samego typu
        this.typZgloszenia = _typZgloszenia;

        if (typZgloszenia == "ZWROT")
       {
           label1.Text = "Zwróć opakowania:";
           btnGetItem.Text = "Zwróć";
           this.emailsender.txt_subject.Text = "Zwrot opakowań";
        }
        else if(typZgloszenia == "ZAMOWIENIE")
        {
            label1.Text = "Zamów opakowania:";
            btnGetItem.Text = "Zamów";
            this.emailsender.txt_subject.Text = "Zamówienie opakowań";
        }
    }

    private void dbopakowania_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ladujZBazy(null, false); 

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.Text == "Zamów opakowania:")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    AddValueToZamówienieOpakowan oknoZamowieniaOpakowania_Szczegoly = new AddValueToZamówienieOpakowan(this, indexes[i]);
                    oknoZamowieniaOpakowania_Szczegoly.ShowDialog();

                    if (doZamowienia != "")
                    {
                        this.emailsender.pozycja++;
                        this.emailsender.txt_msg.Text += emailsender.pozycja.ToString() + "." + " " + doZamowienia;
                        //this.emailsender.txt_subject.Clear();
                        //this.emailsender.txt_subject.Text = "Zamówienie opakowań";
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (label1.Text == "Zwróć opakowania:")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    ZwrotOpakowan oknoZamowieniaOpakowania_Szczegoly = new ZwrotOpakowan(this, indexes[i]);
                    oknoZamowieniaOpakowania_Szczegoly.ShowDialog();

                    if (doZamowienia != "")
                    {
                        this.emailsender.pozycja++;
                        this.emailsender.txt_msg.Text += emailsender.pozycja.ToString() + "." + " " + doZamowienia;
                        //this.emailsender.txt_subject.Clear();
                        //this.emailsender.txt_subject.Text = "Zamówienie opakowań";
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nieoczekiwany Błąd - skontaktuj sie z admin", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    private void btn_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    void ladujZBazy(string mustContains, bool dropIndexes) 
    {
       if (dropIndexes)

        {
         checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
         listOpakowaniaTabela.Clear();
         indexes.Clear();
        }

        bazaproduktowDBEntities dc = new bazaproduktowDBEntities();

        var c1 = from d in dc.OpakowaniaTabela select d.NazwaOpakowania;
        var c2 = from d in dc.OpakowaniaTabela select "(" + d.PartiaOpakowania + ")";
        var c3 = from d in dc.OpakowaniaTabela select d.IloscOpakowania;
        var c4 = from d in dc.OpakowaniaTabela select d.JednostkaOpakowania;

        listOpakowaniaTabela.Add(c1.ToList());
        listOpakowaniaTabela.Add(c2.ToList());
        listOpakowaniaTabela.Add(c3.ToList());
        listOpakowaniaTabela.Add(c4.ToList());

        for (int i = 0; i < listOpakowaniaTabela[0].Count; i++)
        {
            string strToAdd = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < listOpakowaniaTabela.Count; j++)
            {
                strToAdd += " " + listOpakowaniaTabela[j][i] + " ";
            }
            if (mustContains == null)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(strToAdd);
                indexes.Add(i);
            }
            else if (strToAdd.ToLower().Contains(mustContains.ToLower()))
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(strToAdd);
                indexes.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ladujZBazy(textBox1.Text, false); //false
    }

}
```

Any Solution? C#

Comment: If you remove all elements from the CheckedListBox, then of course the checked state of those elements is removed as well. Adding new elements to the CheckedListbox creates those elements in their default, unchecked state. If you need to transfer/keep checked state across old and new elements somehow, you will need to copy the checked state from each old element to the respective new element. Or, much simpler, just don't remove the elements which you want to keep (including their unchecked/checked state) in the CheckedListBox...